# Dictionary key in python are RegExp

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a dictionary where the keys would be a regexp. I want to compare one value with different keys. For example, I want the same value for these keys:

```
int(1), int(2) ... int(10)
```

and that is not for everyone to create keys, I need to have one regular expression for all possible keys. How can I do this?

Approximate example of dictionary:

```
dict = {'int([0-9]*)': 128, 'tinyint([0-9]*)': 64}
```

Can I do without cycles?

I check has not reached a limit value in the MYSQL. Limit for the field - always same. A type field may be `int(1), int(2)...int(11)`

I'm getting from MYSQL value to the type of the field in the tuple:

`type_field = (u'number ', u'int (10)', u'NO ', u'PRI', None, u'auto_increment ')`

And

`>>> print type_field[1]`

`int (10)`

I want to appeal directly to the value of the dictionary by key `type_field[1]`, without a cycle. Like this:

`di[type_field[1]]`

With any number in `int(number)` from 1 to 11, I would receive the same value. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, can you provide some testcases? Show us sample input and expected output for this input. What dict values means? Where are they coming from? How are you adding data to your dict?

Comment: You'll probably want to make your own preprocessing hash function to first get a key.

Comment: Is this having to do with bit masks?

Comment: Do you mean globing? Like [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

Comment: `Is it possible?` Yes, of course it is possible. If they can put a man on the moon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally mean *keys that are regex's*, they are hashable objects in Python:

```
>>> {re.compile(r'int([0-9]*)'): 128}
{<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x10cbd6200>: 128}
```

Which means you can do something like:

```
>>> di={re.compile(r'a'): 'ay in there', re.compile('b'): 'bees in there'}
>>> for s in ('say', 'what', 'you', 'mean', 'bag'):
...     print s, [di[k] for k in di if k.search(s)]
... 
say ['ay in there']
what ['ay in there']
you []
mean ['ay in there']
bag ['ay in there', 'bees in there']
```

Or just use the strings that represent the regex before it is used:

```
>>> di={r'^\w\w?a': '"a" is second or third letter' , r'^[^aeiou][aeiou]': "vowel after non-vowel"}
>>> for s in ('aaa', 'bag', 'box', 'drag'):
...     print s, [di[k] for k in di if re.search(k, s)]
... 
aaa ['"a" is second or third letter']
bag ['vowel after non-vowel', '"a" is second or third letter']
box ['vowel after non-vowel']
drag ['"a" is second or third letter']
```

---

Based on you update, it would seem to me that a list comprehension is what you are looking for:

```
li=[
(u'number ', u'int (10)', u'NO ', u'PRI', None, u'auto_increment '),
(u'number ', u'int (22)', u'NO ', u'PRI', None, u'auto_increment '),
(u'number ', u'int (11)', u'NO ', u'PRI', None, u'auto_increment '),
]

>>> [e for e in li if 1<int(re.search(r'\((\d+)\)$', str(e[1])).group(1))<11]
[(u'number ', u'int (10)', u'NO ', u'PRI', None, u'auto_increment ')]
```

Something other than that, you will probably need to create a class to do something more specialized. From what you are *describing* I think you still need to think through the details a bit more.

Comment: For added usability, write a custom `RegexDict` that'll do that for you: `__getitem__(self, index): return [di[k] for k in self if k.search(index)]`.  You'd probably want to implement enough of `dict`'s interface to use `collections.MutableMapping`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regex you can just use `format` within a dict comprehension :

```
{'int({})'.format(i):j for i,j in zip(range(1,len(val_list)+1),val_list)}
```

Example :

```
>>> val_list=['a','b','c','d']
>>> {'int({})'.format(i):j for i,j in zip(range(1,len(val_list)+1),val_list)}
{'int(1)': 'a', 'int(4)': 'd', 'int(2)': 'b', 'int(3)': 'c'}
```

Comment: Seems pretty space inefficient, since it seems like a lot of keys map to the same value.

Comment: @C.B. So what you suggest?

Comment: Well the idea is outlined in my comment, but I agree with Nsh that more context is needed.

Answer (score 0):

regular expression patterns can be pre-compiled and stored anywhere you want.

so you create the pattern and store them as the key, and then your numerical output as the value.

```
import re

patt_dict = {
    re.compile('int\([0-9]*\)'): 128,
    re.compile('tinyint\([0-9]*\)'): 64
    }
```

now assuming you're reading a table create statement from a file

```
total_size = 0
with open('create_stmt.txt') as sql_fl:
    for line in sql_fl:
        for key, value in patt_dict.iteritems():
            if re.findall(key, line.strip()):
                total_size += value
print total_size
```

keep in mind that this is an O(n*m) algorithm. I'm not sure yet how to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all. I did like this:

```
limits = {'tinyint': 127, 'tinyint unsigned': 255}
field_autoincrement = ('zxzxzxz', 'tinyint(4) unsigned', 'dsdsds')
limit = limits[re.compile('\(\d+\)').sub('', field_autoincrement[1])]
>>>limit
255
```